# Sort in shell scripting unique in multiple columns

Tags: sorting

I have a scenario as below.
In a file say file1.txt, I have

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 5
B 2
C 9
C 10
```

I would like to sort and get results like below.

```
A 3
B 5
C 10
```

I tried

sort fike1.txt -k1,1 -kn2

But didn't work.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to get max value of each character and show character in sorted order.

Comment: Can u share with an example please.